# Try to install DB2 connector for requesting IBMi (AS400) on CentOS 8

Tags: database, centos, db2, ibm-midrange

I have to install DB2 PHP driver on Centos 8 for make requests to IBMi (AS400) with PHP 7 and nginx, I try to find a guide but unfortunately i can't find anything.
So I ask you, do you have a link or tips for this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely want to use the IBM i Access ODBC driver.

[IBM i Access for Linux: Open Database Connectivity](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzatv/rzatvodbc.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options depending on how much you want to spend.

ODBC - This is likely going to be your least expensive option. You can get the drivers from the IBM i Access product mentioned by jamesallman. The IBM customer likely already has IBM i Access Client Solutions, and would already be licensed to use the driver. If you don't have the Linux drivers, [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/odbc-driver-ibm-i-access-client-solutions) is a starting point.

IBM_DB2 / PDO_DB2 - both of these need a DB2 client. The client required by IBM i is provided with the [DB2 Connect](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/db2-connect) product. If you don't already have a license for that, it is also available from IBM, but it is in the "If you have to ask, it's too expensive" category.